# Track changes to lists and dictionaries in python?

Tags: python

I have a class where the instances of this class needs to track the changes to its attributes.

Example: `obj.att = 2` would be something that's easily trackable by simply overriding the `__setattr__` of `obj`.

However, there is a problem when the attribute I want to change is an object itself, like a list or a dict.

How would I be able to track things like `obj.att.append(1)` or `obj.att.pop(2)`?

I'm thinking of extending the list or the dictionary class, but monkey patching instances of those classes once the `obj` and the `obj.att` is both initialized so that `obj` gets notified when things like `.append` is called. Somehow, that doesn't feel very elegant.

The other way that I can think of would be passing an instance of `obj` into the list initialization, but that would break a lot of existing code plus it seems even less elegant than the previous method.

Any other ideas/suggestions? Is there a simple solution that I'm missing here?

Comment: what about making the objects intern and allow access from outside only over getter and setter classes?

Comment: you can serialize the objects and compare the serialized versions.

Comment: I agree with joni. Consider the Law of Demeter here. Alternatively, disallow access to `attr` directly but provide getters and setters that create a deep copy.

Comment: [`traits`](https://github.com/enthought/traits)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was curious how this might be accomplished when I saw the question, here is the solution I came up with.  Not as simple as I would like it to be but it may be useful.  First, here is the behavior:

```
class Tracker(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.lst = trackable_type('lst', self, list)
        self.dct = trackable_type('dct', self, dict)
        self.revisions = {'lst': [], 'dct': []}


>>> obj = Tracker()            # create an instance of Tracker
>>> obj.lst.append(1)          # make some changes to list attribute
>>> obj.lst.extend([2, 3])
>>> obj.lst.pop()
3
>>> obj.dct['a'] = 5           # make some changes to dict attribute
>>> obj.dct.update({'b': 3})
>>> del obj.dct['a']
>>> obj.revisions              # check out revision history
{'lst': [[1], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2]], 'dct': [{'a': 5}, {'a': 5, 'b': 3}, {'b': 3}]}
```

Now the `trackable_type()` function that makes all of this possible:

```
def trackable_type(name, obj, base):
    def func_logger(func):
        def wrapped(self, *args, **kwargs):
            before = base(self)
            result = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
            after = base(self)
            if before != after:
                obj.revisions[name].append(after)
            return result
        return wrapped

    methods = (type(list.append), type(list.__setitem__))
    skip = set(['__iter__', '__len__', '__getattribute__'])
    class TrackableMeta(type):
        def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
            for attr in dir(base):
                if attr not in skip:
                    func = getattr(base, attr)
                    if isinstance(func, methods):
                        dct[attr] = func_logger(func)
            return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)

    class TrackableObject(base):
        __metaclass__ = TrackableMeta

    return TrackableObject()
```

This basically uses a metaclass to override every method of an object to add some revision logging if the object changes.  This is not super thoroughly tested and I haven't tried any other object types besides `list` and `dict`, but it seems to work okay for those.

Comment: Yeah basically, I was trying to find a simple way to do it in such a way that you wouldn't have to create separate `list` and `dict` subclasses and figure out which methods you need to patch, obviously what I came up with isn't that simple :)

Answer (score 5):

You could take advantage of the abstract base classes in the collections module, which dict and list implement. This gives you a standard library interface to code against with a short list of methods to override, `__getitem__, __setitem__, __delitem__, insert`. Wrap the attributes in a trackable adapter inside `__getattribute__`.

```
import collections

class Trackable(object):
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        attr = object.__getattribute__(self, name)
        if isinstance(attr, collections.MutableSequence):
            attr = TrackableSequence(self, attr)
        if isinstance(attr, collections.MutableMapping):
            attr = TrackableMapping(self, attr)
        return attr

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
        # add change tracking


class TrackableSequence(collections.MutableSequence):
    def __init__(self, tracker, trackee):
        self.tracker = tracker
        self.trackee = trackee

    # override all MutableSequence's abstract methods
    # override the the mutator abstract methods to include change tracking


class TrackableMapping(collections.MutableMapping):
    def __init__(self, tracker, trackee):
        self.tracker = tracker
        self.trackee = trackee

    # override all MutableMapping's abstract methods
    # override the the mutator abstract methods to include change tracking
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of monkey patching, you can create a proxy class:

- Make a proxy class that inherit from dict/list/set whatever
- Intercept attribute setting, and if the value is a dict/list/set, wrap it into the proxy class
- In proxy class `__getattribute__`, make sure the method is called on the wrapped type, but take care of tracking before doing so.

Pro:

- no class alteration

Con:

- you are limited to a number of types you know and expect

Answer (score 2):

You can also wrap the dictionary or list methods you want to track and make sure you do what you want inside the wrapper. Here is a dict example:

```py
from functools import wraps

def _setChanged(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrappedFunc(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.changed = True
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrappedFunc

def _trackObjectMethods(calssToTrack):
    for methodName in dir(calssToTrack):
        if methodName in calssToTrack._destructive:
            setattr(calssToTrack, methodName, _setChanged(getattr(calssToTrack, methodName)))

class Dictionary(dict):
    _destructive = ('__delitem__', '__setitem__', 'clear', 'pop', 'popitem', 'setdefault', 'update')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.changed = False
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

_trackObjectMethods(Dictionary)

d = Dictionary()
print(d.changed)
d["1"] = 'test'
print(d.changed)
d.changed = False
print(d.changed)
d["12"] = 'test2'
print(d.changed)
```

As you can see if any items of the dictionary changes, the custom variable that I added to my custom Dictionary object will be set to True. This way I can tell if the object has changes since the last time I had set the changed variable to False.

Answer (score 1):

My [jsonfile](https://github.com/SzieberthAdam/jsonfile) module detects changes of (nested) JSON compatible Python objects. Just subclass `JSONFileRoot` to adapt change detection for your needs.

```
>>> import jsonfile
>>> class Notify(jsonfile.JSONFileRoot):
...   def on_change(self):
...     print(f'notify: {self.data}')
... 
>>> test = Notify()
>>> test.data = 1
notify: 1
>>> test.data = [1,2,3]
notify: [1, 2, 3]
>>> test.data[0] = 12
notify: [12, 2, 3]
>>> test.data[1] = {"a":"b"}
notify: [12, {'a': 'b'}, 3]
>>> test.data[1]["a"] = 20
notify: [12, {'a': 20}, 3]
```

Note that it goes on the proxy class way how e-satis advised, without supporting sets.