# Python inheritance best practice for 'object histories'

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a number of classes (e.g. Contact) for which I also want to track the change history. Below is my starting point. I imagine this is a common use case, so would appreciate guidance on best practice here. Would this be a good place to use multiple inheritance, and what would that look like?

```
from datetime import date

class ContactHistory(object):
    def __init__(self, contact, change_action, change_user_id, change_source):
        self.name = contact.name
        self.phone = contact.phone
        self.email = contact.email
        self.change_action = change_action
        self.change_user_id = change_user_id
        self.change_source = change_source
        self.change_date = date.today()

    def __repr__(self):
        return '%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s' % (self.name, self.email, self.phone, self.change_action, self.change_user_id, self.change_source, self.change_date)

class Contact(object):
    def __init__(self, name, phone, email, change_user_id, change_source):
        self.name = name
        self.phone = phone
        self.email = email
        self.history = []       
        self.history.append(ContactHistory(self, 'created', change_user_id, change_source))

    def update_phone(self, phone, change_user_id, change_source):
        self.phone = phone
        self.history.append(ContactHistory(self, 'phone updated', change_user_id, change_source))

    def get_history(self):
        return self.history

contact = Contact('Bill', '214-555-1212', 'me', 'admin page')
contact.update('972-555-1212', 'me', 'contact management page')
print contact.get_history()
```

Comment: Possibly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858525/track-changes-to-lists-and-dictionaries-in-python is of interest.

Comment: There are good things on this link @larsks... @JackOfAll, maybe you want to look up the `memo pattern`? It is not directly what you want, but maybe you'll get some new ideas from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you could use inheritance to approach this.  `ChangeableObject` could be inherited by any object that needed to be changeable, with that object just describing the parameters that are used to create a shallow clone for history:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Change = namedtuple("Change", ("old", "new", "action"))

class History(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.history = []

    def save_change(self, old, new, action):
        change = Change(old, new, action)
        self.history.append(change)

    def get_history(self):
        return self.history

class ChangeableObject(object):
    def __init__(self, make_history=True):
        if make_history:
            self.history = History()
            self.history.save_change(None, self, "created")
        self.cloneable_attributes = ()

    @classmethod
    def get_clone(cls, obj):
        attrs = {attr: getattr(obj, attr) for attr in obj.cloneable_attributes}
        return cls(make_history=False, **attrs)

    def view_history(self):
        return self.history.get_history()

class Contact(ChangeableObject):
    def __init__(self, name, phone, email, make_history=True):
        super(Contact, self).__init__(make_history=make_history)
        self.name = name
        self.phone = phone
        self.email = email
        self.cloneable_attributes = ("name", "phone", "email")

    def update_phone(self, phone):
        clone = self.get_clone(self)
        self.phone = phone
        self.history.save_change(clone, self, "phone updated")

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{} {} {}".format(self.name, self.phone, self.email)
```

With example code:

```
c = Contact("me", "123-123-123", "foo@example.com")
c.update_phone("456-456-456")
print c
for i, hist in enumerate(c.view_history()):
    print "{}. {}".format(i, hist)
```

Output:

```
me 456-456-456 foo@example.com
0. Change(old=None, new=me 456-456-456 foo@example.com, action='created')
1. Change(old=me 123-123-123 foo@example.com, new=me 456-456-456 foo@example.com, action='phone updated')
```

Comment: Thank you! That's very helpful.