# How to find the history of an index in a list?

Tags: python, list, history

So lets say I have this code: `list1 = [1,2,3]`.
So lets say we insert 4 in index 0, `list1 = [4,1,2,3]`.
Is there a way to go backwords and find what the "history" of what was in index 0? This a simplified version of my question, but just imagine many different things happened to change `list1`.

Comment: Definitely not unless you implement your own class or use something 3rd party made.

Comment: You might want to try what's provided in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858525/track-changes-to-lists-and-dictionaries-in-python?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Track changes to lists and dictionaries in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858525/track-changes-to-lists-and-dictionaries-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking for a [persistent data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure). Python lists are *mutable*, and do not store any sort of history (which is a good thing, since the overhead would be very high, and isn't generally desired).

Depending on what you're actually trying to do you might be able to simply create *new* lists, rather than mutate existing ones. For example instead of:

```
ls = [1, 2, 3]
ls.insert(0, 4)
```

Create a new list:

```
ls = [1, 2, 3]
ls2 = [4] + ls
```

This preserves `ls` and lets you compare it to `ls2`.

As cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ suggests you could also implement your own list-like structure that records its history in a journal. It wouldn't be too complicated, but I'd suggest looking into other options first (and verifying this is [really what you need](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147573)), it's not a very common thing to want in practice.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create a hash table for your list so you can check later for history of indices :

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
hash_table={i:j for i,j in enumerate(list1)}
print(hash_table)
```

output:

```
{0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3}
```